# To what extent is someone on the way to do a mitzvah protected from danger?

Tags: mitzvah, talmud-bavli, shlichus-agency, maseches-pesachim, danger

Pesachim 8A [(link)](http://dafyomi.co.il/pesachim/points/ps-ps-008.htm) says:

> R. Elazar taught that harm will not befall a Shali'ach (someone on the way to do a) Mitzvah!

That is a short excerpt from a discussion about being protected when doing a mitzvah in the context of searching for chametz before Pesach where there might be a danger. It seems to say that if someone is going to do a mitzvah, unless there is something especially dangerous, one is protected from harm.

Of what degree of protection does it speak? Protection from death? Major injury that wouldn't heal (loss of limb)? Major injury that doesn't have a major long term effect (hip fracture that is set but has residual minor long-term effects)? Temporary injury (broken toe that gets set and fully healed)? Even temporary minor injury (paper cut)?

Comment: The exception to this rule is if the emissary in the course of his/her travels ventures into a dangerous area, or engages in an inherently risky activity.

http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/592448/jewish/Why-do-some-give-a-coin-to-a-traveler.htm

Comment: @ray Right but I'm talking about the degree of protection, not how dangerous something needs to be. If somebody is biking on campus on his way to Mincha, rushing (though still not a particularly dangerous thing, especially for a young guy who is an experienced biker) so they don't have to wait for him, would he be protected from all harm on the way, only severe harm, only from death, what's the cutoff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the ברייתא cited further in the Gemara, it would appear that any and all damages, even of the slightest and likeliest nature and occurring anywhere on one's property are included in this discussion (at least according to the opinion voiced there, although there is no contradictory sentiment earlier in the discussion that I've detected) [text of Rashi follows that of the Gemara]:

> תניא: **איסי בן יהודה אומר: כלפי שאמרה תורה "ולא יחמד איש את ארצך",
>   מלמד שתהא פרתך רועה באפר ואין חיה מזיקתה, תרנגולתך מנקרת באשפה ואין
>   חולדה מזיקתה; והלא דברים קל וחומר, ומה אלו שדרכן לזוק אינן ניזוקין,
>   בני אדם שאין דרכן לזוק על אחת כמה וכמה; אין לי אלא בהליכה, בחזרה מנין,
>   תלמוד לומר: "ופנית בבקר והלכת לאהליך", מלמד שתלך ותמצא אהלך בשלום.**
>
> **כלפי שאמרה תורה**: מתוך **שאמרה תורה** כך, אנו למדים שהבטיחו הכתוב שלא יוזק ממונו, וכל שכן גופו ד**אין דרכ**ו **לזוק**, דאדם אית ליה מזלא
>   ואינו מהיר להיות ניזק בגופו.

To quote the outline on the page you provided in your question:

> (Beraisa - Isi ben Yehudah): "V'Lo Yachmod Ish Es Artzecha" teaches
>   that one [who goes to Yerushalayim for the festival] may leave his cow
>   grazing in the dirt and his chicken pecking in the wasteheap, and
>   Chayos and weasels will not attack them;
>
> It is normal for animals to be damaged, yet the Torah promises that
>   they will not be [due to the Mitzvah]. All the more so people, who are
>   not normally damaged [because they have Mazel, i.e. supernatural
>   protection], will not be harmed!
>
> Question: This teaches that they will not be harmed on the way. What
>   is the source regarding the way back?
>
> Answer: "U'Fanisa va'Boker v'Halachta l'Ohalecha" - you will return
>   and find your tent b'Shalom (intact).

Comment: Is there any indication if its mention of even the chickens being protected from weasels is an added level of protection specifically allotted to those who go up to Jerusalem, or if the specific mention is simply because that is what would be relevant from one who leaves his farm unattended?

Comment: Actually, this brings to mind an anecdotal, though I think relevant, event. I know someone who was mugged (but uninjured) on the way back from Shul. That would seem parallel to the protection of one's chickens. We're talking about a relatively safe part of LA where lots of Jews walk to Shul on a regular basis (so mugging there wasn't a common concern). How might our understanding of the gemara relate to this incident?

Comment: The Gemara specifically cites this ברייתא as a direct comparison to 'ordinary' שלוחי מצוה (to wit: איתמר: אמר רבי אלעזר: שלוחי מצוה אינן ניזוקין לא בהליכתן ולא בחזירתן; כמאן, כי האי תנא, דתניא...), so yes, it seems that the cases mentioned are simply relevant concerns for an עולה לרגל.

Comment: The question as to how the discussion in the gemara applies to scenarios such as your friend's is an entirely different question which deserves its own page.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, then my question of 'what is the degree of protection' hasn't been directly addressed. (Perhaps the specific scenario I brought up is a little off topic, not sure if it would be worthy of a question itself, but as a whole I'd like a more definitive answer of the level of protection of a typical person on a way to do a mitzvah in a place where a danger is not particularly common.)

Comment: Nowhere in your question did you indicate that you were asking how one may reconcile everyday reality with what the Gemara stated. It seemed pretty clear you wished to have a better understanding of the scope of what the Gemara was actually stating. To that end, I believe the question has been answered satisfactorily.

Comment: To clarify further, as I understand it, and as I believe I demonstrated, the Gemara's protection should be properly understood to cover any sort of damage whatsoever (or at least any emanating from the situation created by performing the mitzva). An entirely different problem exists to the effect that there are countless instances where the Gemara's assertion seemingly did not hold up, your friend's experience ostensibly being no different; in response to that I suggested that you start a question to the effect of: 'how is it that harm befalls שלוחי מצוה if the Gemara says it doesn't'?

Comment: Perhaps I'll take your advice. But your comment above seemed to say that there was some distinction between the level of protection from someone going on a regel to an ordinary shaliach mitzvah. Perhaps I misunderstood, and if the gemara does indeed clearly mean that a shaliach is protected from all harm and loss, then yes you have satisfactorily answered my question.

Comment: I was attempting to say that there is no distinction. My proof is that the opinion of איסי בן יהודה about the pilgrims is cited as a parallel to רבי אלעזר who was discussing ordinary shluchei mitzva (although they are not being compared for the chicken/cow bit but rather regarding the going/returning issue). The only reason why chickens and cows are mentioned specifically here seems to be because that would be the typical concern of a pilgrim. I hope that settles things and I pledge to improve my clarity in the future!

Comment: Before I award the bounty, just one more question. Someone told me that the word choice in the Gemara implies a reference to permanent harm. Can you comment on that?

Comment: Not sure which words choice is being referred to. I can't see how the word ניזוקין can be construed to be specifically in reference to permanent damage. And as we've already discussed, the causal reference to chickens and cows indicates that any loss whatsoever as a result of doing a mitzva seems to be included in the damage which is said not to occur. Am I missing anything?

Comment: The person clarified to me as follows: *"The five categories of reimbursement for bodily injury include nezek as one of them, which seems to only include permanent damage (it is the amount that a person loses in market value if they were sold as a slave after they heal versus before they are injured). On that basis, it would seem that the term in Pesachim likely only refers to permanent injury."* So might some kinds of harm, like pain or a flat tire, not be covered in the protection?

Comment: Well, throughout Shas, wherever the context speaks of reimbursement, the היזק clearly has to be of a permanent nature, or else what role would payment play altogether? Even in our discussion, whatever damage to chickens/cows that is explicitly spoken of here might indeed be of a permanent nature too. However I find it unlikely that we can separate permanence from severity here, and assume that permanent damage to a chicken would be included, but “Major injury that doesn't have a major long term effect” would not...

Comment: …The context here speaks nothing of payment, and I don’t think that נזק is linguistically tied to permanence everywhere. To my mind, the term ‘נזק’ is generally a parallel to ‘harm’, unless the context is legalistic in which case it might more accurately be ‘damage’. However, once again, considering the context here, to think that Chazal were making a fine legalistic distinction here by stating ‘ניזוקין’ seems like a stretch to me. P.S. Flat tires don’t fix themselves!

Comment: What do you mean by "'Major injury that doesn't have a major long term effect' would not."?

Comment: Am quoting you in the original question! The fellow's chicken won't be killed, but every bone in his body might just shatter requiring 5 years of reconstructive surgery and physical therapy that will leave him as good as new? Seems unlikely and not in consonance with the Gemara's intent.