# How is it that harm befalls a shaliach mitzvah if the Gemara says it doesn't?

Tags: health-safety-shmira, talmud-bavli, maseches-pesachim, hashgacha-pratit

As a followup on [this answer from another question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30177/1947), the [Gemara on Pesachim 8a](http://dafyomi.co.il/pesachim/points/ps-ps-008.htm) seems to say that a shaliach mitzvah, someone who is doing a mitzvah or on the way to do one or even on the way back is protected from (seemingly all) harm/damage/loss/danger (provided it is not especially dangerous). However in real life this doesn't seem to be the case. I personally have two examples of this off the top of my head:

- My grandmother, while walking home from Shul in a relatively safe area, was mugged. She only lost property.
- A couple years ago I was biking on campus, trying to rush to meet someone after class so we could go to Mincha on time and so he wouldn't have to wait. Normally a young guy like me biking on campus, even if hurrying, isn't considered something particularly dangerous. But when crossing grass, some other biker came up on the path ahead perpendicular, I tried to stop quickly to avoid hitting them, but I braked and I lost traction and fractured my hip. I was in plenty of pain, had setbacks in school, there were of course monetary costs involved, and while mostly healed I still am not completely back to normal.

So why do events such as these happen if the Gemara seems to promise protection? Are they not "covered"? Does the protection not apply?

Comment: Why do bad things happen to good people?

Comment: There is a gemara in Kiddushin 39 which has the shittah of Rav Yaakov,see it there for the back and forth.It is a different take and it also answers Achers question.

Comment: @DoubleAA, what's the relevance of your question? The asker here is referring to a specific protection.

Comment: @msh as opposed to what: a specific protection of sechar vaonesh?

Comment: @sam The case there was when the child was going up a clearly dangerous, rickety ladder. In the case of Pesachim 8, it clearly implies that if there's a risk of scorpions in rubble, reaching your hand in the rubble to look for chometz would be protected by the mitzvah of bedikas chometz. (It rules not to do this for other concerns, but the point remains.) The danger cutoff is somewhere between maybe scorpions and a clearly rickety ladder, and I don't think either example in my question is in "clearly dangerous" territory.

Comment: @DoubleAA Reward vs punishment and good vs bad is not relevant to this question. The protection isn't *reward* for a mitzvah, it's a *specific protection from danger for someone on the way to or returning from or performing* a mitzvah.

Comment: @AL You can assert their irrelevance but apparently I disagree.

Comment: @DoubleAA You might be misunderstanding what I'm asking.... Can you demonstrate the relevance? Or perhaps see Kiddushin 39 referenced by sam above where in the case of the child and the ladder; first they thought the reward for what he's doing (long life) should have prevented his death, but then they say it must mean it refers to olam haba. It's after that, though, that they suggest he should have been saved because of a different principle, the one I asked about (and say he wasn't saved because his situation was clearly dangerous).

Comment: I understand your question

Comment: I have a theory which I may have alluded to in my other comments; before I properly flesh it out, I'd like to test-run it here. In short, in order for the damage to be included, the circumstances which enabled it to occur must be solely due to the performance of a mitzva; if the fellow would have been in an identical situation anyway, then the harm may occur now all the same. I think this is borne out by all the examples in the sugya. Holler back.

Comment: @BarUryan I'm not sure that any examples on this page were of someone being in an identical circumstance to how it would be sans-mitzvah.

Comment: Maybe not at that moment, but nothing about those situations sounds unique; what's so unusual about walking down a/that street, or biking anywhere / on that campus? Contrast with the scenarios in the Gemara.

Comment: @BarUryan I could ask what's so unusual about climbing ladders? Climbing ladder to mitzvah is similar to walking from shul from mitzvah, and the gemara says the only reason he wasn't saved was because it was an obviously dangerous ladder. So I'm not sure I follow why common activities might preclude protection.

Comment: I don't think scaling a tower to retrieve a nest ever was an ordinary activity. It might be argued that the father's instructions were capricious in the first place. And so the son most likely would never have found himself in that situation otherwise.

Comment: @BarUryan "Scaling a tower" isn't the picture that formed in my mind reading the gemara (it just sounded like climbing a tree with a broken ladder), but you could be right. I asked the daf yomi kollel and Rav Moshe Sternbuch, shlit'a said it refers to any harm that could come about due to the fulfillment of a Mitzvah. (So for example even if walking in the street is common, she wouldn't have been right there at that time if not for davening at Shul, and even if biking on campus is common I wouldn't have been in the exact same scenario if not for Mincha, so I'm not sure if that matters.)

Comment: [Definition of בירה](http://he.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%94). Do you understand what RMS said to be along the lines of my answer or do you think there is a distinction?

Comment: @BarUryan Oh you're right, building, I misread. So yeah that sounds dangerous. As to your answer compared to Rav Sternbuch's, I think there is a distinction. You seem to say that protection is only for (relatively safe yet) uncommon types of activities. He seems to say that protection is for any difference between what you do and what you would have done without the mitzvah....

Comment: ...So according to him, it seems getting in your car 15 seconds later because you're doing a mitzvah you shouldn't have to worry that you'll be right in the spot where a drunk is speeding through a red light, but if I'm not mistaken, according to you since driving is common there would be no protection. The difference between RMS and what most people do, however, ***might*** be that if you have shaliach mitzva money on your airplane flight that it's less likely to crash, but since you'd be in the same exact seat/flight without the money maybe there wouldn't be protection for the flight.

Comment: @AL I wrote my question before you revised your comment to include the parenthesis, and so upon reading them earlier I had my answer. Yes, it would appear that you have summed up the differences well. As I wrote in my full answer below, I think my interpretation fits well with all the cases throughout the Gemara, and would seem to be less at odds with a lot of people's experiences.

Comment: Has your hip healed since then? Does that change the nature of this question at all?

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel I'm far from the only example of harm befalling a Shaliach Mitzvah so I don't think it would be relevant one way or the other; my examples were only illustrative because it was my personal experience. If this answer https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30177 is correct then even minor monetary loss would be covered in which case it would also be immaterial. Regardless, I'm not the one who just set a bounty on this question, so if you're preparing an answer, know that I'm not the main person you have to satisfy.

Comment: Very well. Anyways, how’s your hip??

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel I'm okay now, save for some fairly minor issues. My question was asked a couple years after the accident and not much has changed since the asking. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 2):

I was at a Shiva where Rabbi Avigdor Miller Zatzal attended. The one sitting Shiva asked Rabbi Miller regarding the Nifteres - who was his wife. She was on the way to go do a Mitzva and was hit by a bus. How could this have happened? Do we not say that a Shliacha Mitzva does not get harmed. Rabbi Miller responded that in a place where it is ("Shechiach Hezaika") common to get damaged, this promise does not work.

Comment: The question notes this but claims its examples were not in dangerous places.

Comment: I'm confused by his answer; did people constantly get hit by busses where his wife was? Was it more risky than the case of a scorpion possibly being in rubble?

Comment: @AL: I do not know when you say Shechiach Hezaika and when not. Perhaps motor vehicles are dangerous and there are accidents at all times and that qualifies it for Shechiach Hezaika. Both of your examples - getting mugged and bike accidents would in my eyes be as common as a motor vehicle accident.

Comment: @GershonGold If a billion people do a slightly dangerous thing and you say "100 pepole got killed doing this!" I don't think that matters. It's the percentage. The odds of getting hit by a bus when are almost zero. People rummaging through rubble in a country with scorpions is probably a higher risk than that.

Comment: It's circular reasoning (maybe even by the Gemara) and there is a logical disconnect in the unqualified assumption when saying, "It is impossible for a shomer mitzvah to get harmed anywhere it's not dangerous. A shomer was harmed. It *must* have been dangerous." You just say after the fact that any time someone was harmed it must have been dangerous! If you saw someone giving out tzeddaka on his front porch yet become the victim of a robbery or shooting or snake bite would you say even then it must be dangerous? Must everything be due to danger? (Is there even *any* demonstrated protection?)

Comment: @AL: I answered your question, and now it seems that you are asking a different question. Your question was "So why do events such as these happen if the Gemara seems to promise protection? Are they not "covered"? Does the protection not apply?" The answer is "Shechiach Hezaika". Now you are asking "Is there even any demonstrated protection?" which is a different question.

Comment: It's a Gemara in Pesachim

Comment: what rabbi miller said is a quote from chulin 142a

Comment: @GershonGold You're focusing on my parenthetical statement which, reworded, is that by your logic there might even be no protection and the reason is that everything is dangerous. What I'm doing is challenging your answer because I find it questionable, whether or not it was given by an authority. You're denying the antecedent. Put another way, you're overlooking alternatives (could anything else result in a lack of protection?). And that may be fine if I'm asking about serious risk (clear danger of rickety ladder) as opposed to possible danger (as in possible scorpions in rubble).

Comment: @chacham The Gemara there is the same as already mentioned earlier, Kiddushin 39.

Comment: @AL so maybe it was hirhur of Avodah zara?

Comment: @chacham Are there any other possibilities? I'm quite confident we weren't thinking about doing avoda zarah.

Comment: @GershonGold So I'm basically wondering if there are any other possible alternatives other than danger (not to say your answer is definitely wrong, after all walking at night and biking in a hurry are slightly more risky than walking in the daytime or biking slowly, but I'm challenging it because that answer is weak as I've explained earlier). You can even challenge my premise (that injuries and loss of property are the types of danger protected against) which is just based on one answer on my other question.

Comment: Somehow only noticed this question/discussion now. From the example offered in Pesachim it would appear that שכיח היזקא means that the dangerous outcome would be the obvious, natural, almost-guaranteed outcome; not "common". Shaul probably never killed a single prophet on the way to anointing a new king before; but being killed as a result of creating this admittedly novel situation would still be a no-brainer. It's noteworthy that the Gemara later states that even אלו שדרכן לזוק אינן ניזוקין. [Also note the parallel text in Yoma: היכא דקביע היזקא שאני; Rashi: קביע היזקא, מזומנות תמיד].

Answer (score 2):

Here are my thoughts: it would appear that there are 3 possible degrees of protection we can understand the Gemara to be promising: 1) Any and all damage occurring concurrently with the performance of a mitzva (eg. stock value falling while davening mincha), 2) Any and all damage occurring on the scene of performing a mitzva (eg. being hit by a car on the way to mincha), or 3) (and this is what I'm suggesting) Any and all damage that would occur solely due to unique circumstances created exclusively by performing the mitzva (eg. driving to another state to help complete a minyan for mincha). The first 2 are exceptionally broad and, I suspect, are constantly upended by reality. I'd argue that it is in fact the 3rd, narrow definition which is the correct application of the Gemara.

I believe this is borne out by all the examples in Shas: a) sticking one's hand into a scorpion nest; b) creepily scoping a shared wall in the middle of the night by candlelight; c) anointing a new king during his rival's lifetime; d) trekking across a dark, deserted mountainous route; e) completely abandoning one's possessions for a week or more (Pesachim); f) illegally attaching/replacing a mysterious scroll to/on the gate of a city (Yoma); and g) scaling a tower (Kiddushin).

None of these are things that would ever otherwise happen if not for someone attempting to perform a mitzva. So one can argue that the protection afforded is applicable only if: i) the situation is a direct result of the mitzvah, and ii) it is so unique to have never been possible otherwise.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. I'm not sure if it seems that way just because the scope is too narrow to find counterexamples (an activity you might do only once a year, times it being only for a very specific purpose, that would typically be safe to do anyway) or if it's objectively the best understanding of the literature. But you could be right.

Comment: This answer is similar to the explanation of the Maharsha (*Shabbos* 118b "ממתים בדרך מצוה כו'. לא שייך בזה דשלוחי מצוה אינן נזוקין דהיינו ע"י עסק המצות לא היו נזוקין והכא מיירי בדרך מצוה במת בעת שעסק במצוה ולא ע"י עסק מצוה"), reconciling Rabbi Yosi's statement ("May my portion [in the World to Come] be among those who die on the way to performing a *mitzvah*") with the statement in *P'sachim*.

Answer (score -3):

Two answer your specific examples

1) There is no Mitzvah for a woman to go to Shul.

2) You say you `tried to stop quickly to avoid hitting them`. This is something that is Shchiach Hezeika. Relying on your theory, you could have continued going straight and the other person would have stopped instead, and you might have remained unhurt.

Comment: 1. You confuse "mitzvah" with "chiyuv." 2. He was on his way to Mincha. Why should your theory override?